# Restricting label/line drawing to 45 deg. lines?

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, geometry-generator

I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcaX5hlwNQ0) to be able to move label positions and draw lines to connect them to the label dots, but I'd like to restrict the line drawing to 45˚ angles.

Is there a way to do that? I see [this in the changelog for QGIS 3.8](http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.8/#geometry-generators-for-labeling) but can't figure out how to implement.

[image: map with messy labels]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by restricting the line to 45˚? Is it drawing labels only in a range from 0˚ to 45˚, or bigger than 45˚, or just 45˚ for all lines?

Comment: 45 for all lines!

Comment: I think @kazuhito has answered your question but just as a FYI QGIS 3.10 (meant to come out in the next few days...) will have inbuilt label leader options - I presume there will be an option that snaps to certain angles... https://twitter.com/northroadgeo/status/1160421820987613184

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to move the label and line by a fixed distance (a 50m-case below);

[image]

Then the Geometry Generator expression for the **Label** would be:

```
project($geometry, 50, radians(45))
```

[image]

And the associated leader **Line** would be:

```
make_line($geometry, project($geometry, 50, radians(45)))
```

[image]

Perhaps you want more control over the offset distance, then prepare a field (such as "dist") and change `project($geometry, 50, radians(45))` part to `project($geometry, "dist", radians(45))` .